# Devise/Omniauth test failing: No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:facebook}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, omniauth, testunit

I am using Devise 2.2.0 and omniauth 1.1.1 under rails 3.2.11.

I have a test on an un-authenticated (e.g. no "before_filter :authenticate_user!") controller called "HomepageController" with an action called "homepage". This controller action is extremely simple in that it passes through to its view unless the user is signed in, in which case it redirects to our "homebase" page. Here is the controller actions:

```
class HomepageController < ApplicationController
  def homepage
if current_user then
  redirect_to :homebase
end
  end
end
```

Here is my test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomepageControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = users(:donley)
  end

  test "should get homepage when signed in" do
    sign_in @user
    get :homepage
    assert_redirected_to "/homebase"
  end

  test "should get homepage when not signed in" do
    get :homepage
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

The second test fails with this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"omniauth_callbacks", :action=>"passthru", :provider=>:facebook}
```

on this line in the view:

```
= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) do
```

here are my devise and omniauth routes:

```
  resources :oauth_clients

  match '/oauth/test_request',  :to => 'oauth#test_request',  :as => :test_request

  match '/oauth/token',         :to => 'oauth#token',         :as => :token

  match '/oauth/access_token',  :to => 'oauth#access_token',  :as => :access_token

  match '/oauth/request_token', :to => 'oauth#request_token', :as => :request_token

  match '/oauth/authorize',     :to => 'oauth#authorize',     :as => :authorize

  match '/oauth',               :to => 'oauth#index',         :as => :oauth

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}

  devise_scope :user do
    get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "sign_up", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
    match "sign_out", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
```

Here is a route from `rake routes` that looks like the one mentioned in the error message:

```
user_omniauth_authorize /users/auth/:provider(.:format) omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|linkedin/}
```

The really crazy thing is that all this code works perfectly when running in `rails server` or on Heroku in my production environment. It only fails in test.

Many thanks for any insights!

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but... Your homepage logic shouldn't use a redirect like that. You should use devise's helper `authenticated`, like this: http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-5-authenticated-root-and-dashboard-routes-with-devise/

Comment: Ashitaka, That might not answer this question, but it might solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am weirdly getting the exact same issue (`rails s` works just fine), and I already was using an `authenticated :user` block so that link does not help me.

Comment: I am sorry, but, no. I ended up removing the test case. The code was so trivial I couldn't justify any more time spent fixing the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today and found I was not adding Facebook as a provider in the test environment. This should be done in the `devise.rb` initializer. I guess that is why the route was not being generated when I ran the tests.

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
if Rails.env.test?
  config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
end
```